# Get missing number from int array with Java streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have following array,

```
int [] a = {5,3,10,8,4,2,9,6};
```

I am trying get the missing number from tha array,

```
private static int getMissingNumber(int[] a) {
    int expectedSum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
            .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    int actualSum = Arrays.stream(a).reduce(0, Integer::sum);

    return expectedSum-actualSum;
}
```

But is getting 8 instead of 7. What am I missing here?

Comment: what would be the expected output for `{5,3,10,8,4,2,9,1};`?

Comment: I was checking for single missing number. Here two numbers are missing.

Comment: sure, but one should not assume that the input would always be correct, isn't it? (especially when it's not sorted and does not have a base index to start off with)

Answer (score 2):

You minimal value is `2` so should be the start of the range `IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 10)`

Also you can directly call `.sum()` on `IntStream`

```
private static int getMissingNumber(int[] a) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 10).sum() - Arrays.stream(a).sum();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 2 instead of 1 ,

`IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 10)`

You can also find min and max elements in the array using `summaryStatistics()`,

```
private static int getMissingNumber(int[] a) {
    IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = Arrays.stream(a).summaryStatistics();
    int expectedSum = IntStream.rangeClosed(summaryStatistics.getMin(), summaryStatistics.getMax())
            .sum();
    int actualSum = (int) summaryStatistics.getSum();

    return expectedSum-actualSum;
}
```

Comment: I wanted something exactly like this. So array can start with any element and can have n elements. Thank you.

Comment: Replace `.reduce(0, Integer::sum)` with `.sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the numbers from 1 to 10 Is 10 * (10+1) / 2 = 55. You are missing 1 and 7, so the sum of the missing numbers is 8. Looks right to me.

Comment: I wanted from 2 only. I was checking with arrays starting with 20 as well. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you use larger arrays, consider calculating the reference sum using above formula (use it twice if the starting index is variable). It will be much faster and consume less memory. No need to use streams if the result can be calculated using a simple formula.

Comment: How to use above formula with dynamic min value. Stream can give me min, max and sum in one go.

Comment: Let m be the min value, n the max value. Then s = (n*(n+1)-m*(m+1))/2. Also in one go.

Comment: first I have find the min and max, then this is fine.

Comment: You can combine it with the answer from @Code_Mode. Use IntSummaryStatistics to determine min and max values, then calculate the expected sum with the formula.